# complex if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How would I write a complex if statement where the following criteria need to be met for a "true" alert.
price < 25 and hardcover
price < 15 and softcover
pubYear is after 2000
the book is a NewYorkTImes Bestseller
and the series title is "Packers Football"

bookObject=(price, pubYear, seriesTitle, NYTBS, seriesTitle)

Comment: you could use && operator, but i don't get your question indeed

Comment: I am trying to write an if statement where all the criteria are evaluated in one if conditional. It is searching for whether it is a HB or PB book and the price and the year and is a bestseller and has the title "Packers Football" as a series title.

Comment: @FileasFogg The *intent* of your question is clear. How to *accomplish* it is not, because we don't know what your object model is - we can't possibly guess what the name and type of the properties you need to check are. That's what you need to add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be that complicated. Something like:

```
if(book.price < 25
   && book.hardcoverPrice < 15
   && book.softcoverPubYear > 2000
   && book.isNYTBestSeller
   && book.series.title == 'Packers Football')
```

But without knowing how you've set up your JavaScript objects, it's impossible for me to give you a correct answer.

Comment: I think I miss typed the original question. The book is either hardcover or softcover. So wouldn't I need an OR operator between the first and second conditions?

Comment: @FileasFogg - If you go back and fix your original question, I might better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to write an if statement where all the criteria are evaluated in one if conditional. It is searching for whether it is a HB or PB book and the price and the year and is a bestseller and has the title "Packers Football" as a series title. –

Comment: It like I'm at a bookstore and want certain books placed on one table.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
if (b.price < 25 &&
    b.hardcoverPrice < 15 &&
    b.softcoverPubYear > 2000 &&
    b.isNewYorkTimesBestSeller &&
    b.seriesTitle === "Packers Football") {
  alert("The message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include an OR operator between conditional use parentheses. Maybe something like this:

```
if(book.price < 25
   && (book.hardcoverPrice < 15 || book.softcoverPubYear > 2000)
   && book.isNYTBestSeller
   && book.series.title == 'Packers Football')
```